# Why might "proud" be correct in a slogan and not "proudly"?

Tags: grammaticality, differences, adverbs, slogan

In the movie *Great Dane Marmaduke,* someone says, "Say it loud. Say it proud."

But *proud* is an adjective, whereas the sentence really needs an adverb, *proudly.* Perhaps the same applies to *loud* as well.

Why is "Say it proud" right?

Comment: "Say it proud" seems like a slogan, which might be taken up and adapted by an individual to "I say it proud". Does that sound possible for where you heard that sentence?

Comment: Thank you Andrew! It is really a slogan, I saw it in a movie called Great Dane Marmaduke,  he said:say it loud! say it proud!  when I asked this question, I added a subject, maybe that's not right, it is supposed to be used without a subject.

Comment: OK: I've edited all that into the question (and removed the subject, since it wasn't in the original).

Comment: "loud" and "proud" are both adjectives modifying "it." Since the writer put them in the sentence [its a sentence with the understood subject (you) as the subject: (you) Say it loud. and (you) Say it proud], there's no need to change them. They mean they same thing as if "loudly" and "proudly" were modifying the verb "Say."

Comment: Thank you Arch Denton, now I know they are the same thing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proud is an adjective, proudly is an adverb.

"I say it proud" means I say it, and I am proud while I am saying it.

"I say it proudly" means I say it in a proud way.

"Proud" means it is me who is proud. "Proudly" means it is my speech that is proud.

Comment: Actually, IMO, "I say it proud" is just an affected expression that goes with "I say it loud".  "I say it proud" and "I say it proudly" mean exactly the same thing.  What do you say proud or proudly?  It.  Same thing.

Comment: Yeah, Kristina Lopez, loud and proud have the same rhythm, it sounds cute, perhaps that's why the dog would say like that. We all know the meaning exactly. Thanks!